# Como escrever um Evento , sem utilizar o visual studio(em .cs ou simplesmente num ficheiro .txt)

Tags: c#, cmd, notepad++

Estou a tentar escrever em EventArgs() um **Enter Event** para **TB1** (textbox)

Este código de **Form1 (in Form1.cs)**, escrevê-lo-ia normalmente com a ajuda do Designer:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    namespace Project1
    {
            // aqui seria o método para o evento Enter que eu queria, o que está abaixo representado
            // para que a letra 'text' desapareça              

        private void TB1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(TB1.Text=="Text")
                {
                    TB1.Text="";
                }
            }
     }
```

**No código abaixo queria implementar o evento que está acima.** O que tencionava saber, é se conseguia **escrever o evento no ficheiro abaixo para que depois seja compilado**

```
        using System;
        using.System.Windows.Forms;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    namespace Project1
    {
    [ComVisible(true)]
        public class EventArgs
        {
            //
            //Summary:
            //provides a value to use with events that do not have event data
            public static readonly EventArgs Empty;

            //
            //Summary:
            //Initializes a new instance of the System.EventArgs class
            public EventArgs()
            {

            }
        }
            public class Form1:Form
            {
                public static void Main()
                {
                     AplicationEnableVisualStyles();
                     Aplication.Run(new Form1());
                }
                public Form1()
                {
                    //textBox1
                  TextBox TB1 = new TextBox();
                TB1.Location = new Point(30, 20);
                TB1.Size = new Size(100, 30);
                TB1.Text = "Text";
                    //add control to textBox
                    this.Controls.Add(TB1);
                }
           }
     }
```

Comment: não sei se estou a ser claro no problema. :S

Answer (score 1):

A resposta é sim, mas o código que voce fez náo faz muito sentido.

A class [`EventArgs`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2) já está definida no namespace `System` nos assemblies `System.Runtime.dll, mscorlib.dll, netstandard.dll`. Ou seja, básicamente ela está presente em todos os projectos que voce cria, uma vez que `mscorlib.dll` é uma dependencia que voce nao pode remover.

O que isto quer dizer é que mesmo que voce defina a sua class `EventArgs` e voce pode fazer isso (voce pode criar classes com nomes iguais desde que elas estejam em namespaces diferentes). A assinatura do evento, que neste caso é `void (object, EventArgs )` usará o `EventArgs` definido no namespace `System` e nao o seu.

Por outras palavras voce criou a class `EventArgs`, mas voce nao precisa, ela já existe.

Uma coisa que falta no seu código é subscrever o evento `Enter` da textbox.

```
TB1.Enter += TB1_Enter;
```